# Read multidimensional group data in R

Tags: r, file

I have done lot of googling but I didn't find satisfactory solution to my problem.
Say we have data file as:

```
Tag v1 v2 v3
A 1 2 3
B 1 2 2
C 5 6 1
A 9 2 7
C 1 0 1
```

The first line is header. The first column is Group id (the data have 3 groups A, B, C) while other column are values.
I want to read this file in R so that I can apply different functions on the data.
For example I tried to read the file and tried to get column mean

```
dt<-read.table(file_name,head=T) #gives warnings
apply(dt,2,mean) #gives NA   NA   NA
```

I want to read this file and want to get column mean. Then I want to separate the data in 3 groups (according to Tag A,B,C) and want to calculate mean(column wise) for each group. Any help

Comment: start by checking the data with str(dt) if all of them are factors then try something like: dt1=cbind(dt[,1],data.frame(apply(dt[,2:4],2,as.numeric))); 
colnames(dt1)=c('Tag','v1','v2','v3') Then you can try things like dt[dt$Tag == A] to create separate groups, or use things like: tapply(dt1$v1,INDEX=dt1$Tag,mean) to get columnwise functions

Comment: Just remember one of the R gotchas:  if a vector is a factor, you must use as.numeric(as.character(factor_vector)) or you will not get what you want.

Comment: @AndresT - Thanks it works. Just some typo error. It should be x<-dt1[dt1$Tag == 'A',]. But just wondering how to get rid of line numbers in x. It has new values but the line numbers are 1 and 4  
 The x is:
   Tag v1 v2 v3<br/>
1   A  1  2  3<br/>
4   A  9  2  7<br/>

Comment: @d.putto, if I understood you correctly in your last comment, you want to get rid of the first column, just try x<- x[,-1]. Also, I think you may want to use the plyr library, the ddply function does everything you are asking for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply(dt,2,mean)` doesn't work because `apply` coerces the first argument to an array via `as.matrix` (as is stated in the first paragraph of the Details section of `?apply`).  Since the first column is character, all elements in the coerced matrix object will be character.

Try this instead:

```
sapply(dt,mean) # works because data.frames are lists
```

To calculate column means by groups:

```
# using base functions
grpMeans1 <- t(sapply(split(dt[,c("v1","v2","v3")], dt[,"Tag"]), colMeans))
# using plyr
library(plyr)
grpMeans2 <- ddply(dt, "Tag", function(x) colMeans(x[,c("v1","v2","v3")]))
```

Comment: the problem is not apply(dt,2,mean). It is just as an example. I want to separate the data according to Tags in different matrix so that functions can be applied on a specific group.